# Match string until a character is found, which is also contained in an optional field

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = "x OPTIONAL() y z(..., ...)"
```

Where OPTIONAL() is indeed optional, so the string may also be:

```
string = "x y z(..., ...)"
```

Using regular expressions, I want to match the string until the first one of these characters is found:

```
([{;=,
```

Beware that OPTIONAL() includes one of the characters above, but the search should not stop at OPTIONAL(.

So I would like to have:

```
x OPTIONAL() y z
```

Or:

```
x y z
```

I'm currently using:

```
re.search("[ \t\n\r\f\v]*(OPTIONAL\(\))?([^([{;=,]+)", string)
```

And the match properly stops at:

```
x y z
```

when OPTIONAL() is not in the string.

However, with OPTIONAL() in the string, the match stops at:

```
x OPTIONAL
```

Comment: Try [`^(?:OPTIONAL\(\)|[^([{;=,])+`](https://regex101.com/r/Wr4P2O/1)

Comment: Yes, it does. Shouldn't this be an answer, so I can approve it?

Comment: I have [posted it with explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984867/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:OPTIONAL\(\)|[^([{;=,])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wr4P2O/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that will match either

  - `OPTIONAL\(\)` - an `OPTIONAL()` suibstring
  - `|` - or
  - `[^([{;=,]` - a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char other thasn `(`, `[`, `{`, `;`, `=`, `,`
- `)+` - one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `(` only if it is preceded by `OPTIONAL`.

```
^(?:[^([{,;=]+|(?<=OPTIONAL)\()+
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IxYUHQ/1)